# wordpress bootstrap carousel inside modal

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, carousel

This is driving me crazy.
Need some help with this, please.

This is basically a bootstrap carousel inside a modal.

I figure some things out, everything's working, but now i need help to control the "data-slide-to" to define which slide opens on the modal window.

Here's what i have so far:

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<div class="span6">
    <a href="#modalVideo-<? the_ID();?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
    <div id="modalVideo-<? the_ID();?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div id="myCarousel-<? the_ID();?>" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php
                $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                                          'category_name' =>'video',
                                          'posts_per_page' => 1
                                          ));
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                    $the_query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="item active">
                    <?php the_content();?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php
            $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                                      'category_name' =>'video',
                                      'offset' => 1
                                      ));
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                $the_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="item">
                <?php the_content();?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel-<? the_ID();?>" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel-<? the_ID();?>" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer but related, I've used models in both Bootstrap 2 and 3 and find they're far more smooth in 3.

Comment: This project was made initially with bootstrap 2, for now i just need to change that function.When i've more time to work on this, i'll update to 3 for sure.